# How to immediately re-raise an exception thrown in any of the worker threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, exception, threadpoolexecutor

I'm using `ThreadPoolExecutor` and need to abort the whole computation in case any of the worker threads fails.

**Example 1.** This prints *Success* regardless of the error, since `ThreadPoolExecutor` does not re-raise exceptions automatically.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def task():
    raise ValueError

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.submit(task)
print('Success')
```

**Example 2.** This correctly crashes the main thread because `.result()` re-raises exceptions. But it waits for the first task to finish, so the main thread experiences the exception with a delay.

```
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def task(should_raise):
    time.sleep(1)
    if should_raise:
        raise ValueError

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.submit(task, False).result()
    executor.submit(task, True).result()
print('Success')
```

How can I notice a worker exception in the main thread (more or less) immediately after it occurred, to handle the failure and abort the remaining workers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, we have to submit the tasks before requesting their results. Otherwise, the threads are not even running in parallel:

```
futures = []
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    futures.append(executor.submit(good_task))
    futures.append(executor.submit(bad_task))
for future in futures:
    future.result()
```

Now we can store the exception information in a variable that is available to both the main thread and the worker threads:

```
exc_info = None
```

The main thread cannot really kill its sub processes, so we have the workers check for the exception information to be set and stop:

```
def good_task():
    global exc_info
    while not exc_info:
        time.sleep(0.1)

def bad_task():
    global exc_info
    time.sleep(0.2)
    try:
        raise ValueError()
    except Exception:
        exc_info = sys.exc_info()
```

After all threads terminated, the main thread can check the variable holding the exception information. If it's populated, we re-raise the exception:

```
if exc_info:
    raise exc_info[0].with_traceback(exc_info[1], exc_info[2])
print('Success')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, I'll implement it like that:

I the main process, I create 2 queues:

1. One to report exceptions,
2. One to notify cancellation.

::

```
import multiprocessing as mp

error_queue = mp.Queue()
cancel_queue = mp.Queue()
```

I create each `ThreadPoolExecutor`, and pass these queues as parameters.

```
class MyExecutor(concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor):
    def __init__(self, error_queue, cancel_queue):
        self.error_queue : error_queue
        self.cancel_queue = cancel_queue
```

Each `ThreadPoolExecutor` has a main loop. In this loop, I first scan the `cancel_queue` to see if a "cancel" message is available.

In the main loop, I also implement an exception manager. And if an erreur occurs, I raise an exception:

```
self.status = "running"
with True:  # <- or something else
    if not self.cancel_queue.empty():
        self.status = "cancelled"
        break
    try:
        # normal processing
        ...
    except Exception as exc:
        # you can log the exception here for debug
        self.error_queue.put(exc)
        self.status = "error"
        break
    time.sleep(.1)
```

In the main process:

Run all `MyExecutor` instance.

Scan the error_queue:

```
while True:
    if not error_queue.empty():
        cancel_queue.put("cancel")
    time.sleep(.1)
```